# How can I easily run different configurations in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration

I have an Java applications which I would like to run with different values of input parameters (specified in the command line). In "Run -> Run Configurations" I have created different configurations corresponding to different values of the input arguments.

I can run these configurations in the same way (throw "Run -> Run Configurations"). But in these case I have to perform to many actions (clicks) to run a particular configuration. Is there a easier (faster) way to do that? For example I expect that I can do it throw "Run -> Run as" but in the drop-dawn menu of the "Run as" I see "(Not Applicable)".

Comment: Would ant be an option for you to automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the toolbar, the Run icon, has a small arrow pointing down. That gives you a list of recent runs with corresponding configurations. This still takes a number of clicks.

I have not been able to figure out how to (if possible) add shortcuts or keybindings to a particular run

Answer (score 1):

Once you have run a particular configuration once (by going through the Run Configurations window) that configuration should show up in the list of run configuration history, so you can just select the drop down arrow and choose that configuration.

Or choose organize favourites and add your configurations.  These should then show up in the drop down list.